# Peertube cannot login while both expired_token and refresh_token is -1

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, video-streaming

I implemented Peertube on my instance server. and after both expired_token and refresh_token has been expired I cannot login user to my peertube account. I try to request token again but it still the same result.

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "c9eb1076ae74e9eb6d0f845ff7fa2d10760b79d7",
    "refresh_token": "6bee17b98f72ca06b9f1f4f5dab74eeebf54ce0d",
    "expires_in": -1,
    "refresh_token_expires_in": -1
}
```

Comment: `Login error {
"err": {
"statusCode": 400,
"status": 400,
"code": 400,
"message": "Missing parameter: `refresh_token`",
"name": "invalid_request",
"stack": "invalid_request: Missing parameter: `refresh_token``